# Android Gmail API setMaxResult not working

Tags: android, gmail-api

I set number of letters in global variable:

```
private static final long MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST = 10;
```

next, I add this condition to get list query:

```
            List<String> labelsId = new ArrayList<>();
        labelsId.add("INBOX");

        ListMessagesResponse response = mService.users().messages().list(user)
                .setLabelIds(labelsId)
                .setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST)
                .execute();
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = mService.users().messages().list(user)
                        .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

but ".setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS_PER_REQUEST)" don't work:

```
Log.i("messages.size()", String.valueOf(messages.size())); //here 1644 not 10
```

Comment: Does the initial size of `response.getMessages()` equal 10? Maybe this error is happening because you keep getting the next page token and getting the messages for the next page, rather than because Gmail is returning 1644 messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the size of the `messages` List which keeps getting added to as you are iterating through the available pages and adding more messages to it.

The first call to `response.getMessages()` should be enough if you only want 10 messages returned, and you won't need the for loop.

Comment: Great! If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left.